# need to save the pdf to local drive with out download popup using jspdf

Tags: jquery, save, jspdf

i have an HTML table with data ,need to save this as PDF using JSPDF
While calling  **pdf.save(filename.pdf)** one popup is appearing now(save or open- look like download) but actually i don't want this popup with out that it need to be save this to my local drive... kindly suggest.

Comment: not doable. Browsers should not provide such access without telling.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to contact the people who created the web browsers you need to support and ask them to add a feature which allows you to save files on the client's hard disk without asking.

Note: This has been suggested in the past and rejected 100% of the time for security reasons. So don't get your hopes up.

Conclusion: Tell your boss/customer that it can't be done and they should be grateful - or how would they like it when every web page could overwrite files on their computer?